# cut /etc/passwd but without colons (:) in the resulting set of fields

Tags: text-processing, cut

I want to list the username, id and group on /etc/passwd using the following format: `username uid gid`

I have used the following:

`cut -d: -f1,3,4 /etc/passwd`

But it returns `username:uid:gid`. How can I format the command to remove the `:` or list without it, like this:

```
root 0 0
daemon 1 1
bin 2 2
...
```

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: @phuclv
root 0 0
daemon 1 1
bin 2 2
and so on. With every user on a new line.

Comment: Don't process `/etc/passwd` (or `/etc/group`) directly.   Use `getent passwd` (or `getent group`) instead.  /etc/passwd is only one of **many** possible sources of data for user account info.  ditto for /etc/group.  See the man pages for `nss`, `getent`, and `nsswitch.conf`.   e.g. using @phuclv's awk example: `getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1, $3, $4}'`

Comment: @cas Please consider writing an answer using `getent` instead of a comment. That way people can upvote it, and it can potentially be selected as the _correct_ answer to achieve what the OP wants.

Comment: @marcelm phuclv's answer does a good job of answering the question (which is why i upvoted it). My comment wasn't an answer, it didn't answer the question (except for copying part of phuclv's answer as an example), it was just a comment that there are good reasons to use `getent` instead of reading /etc/passwd directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what output you want

The simplest way is to translate the delimiter to what you want with `tr`, `sed` or `awk`... For example

```
cut -d: -f1,3,4 /etc/passwd | tr ':' '\t'
cut -d: -f1,3,4 /etc/passwd | sed 's/:/ --- /g'
awk -F: '{ print $1, $3, $4}' /etc/passwd
```

If you want to format as table then use `column`

```
cut -d: -f1,3,4 /etc/passwd | column -t -s ':'
```

Answer (score 5):

My version of cut (cut (GNU coreutils) 8.28) has a `--output-delimiter` argument:

`cut -d: -f 1,3,4 --output-delimiter " " /etc/passwd`

result:

```
root 0 0
daemon 1 1
bin 2 2
sys 3 3
```